# Waitpid does not continue after tracee stopped

Tags: c, linux, ptrace, waitpid

I using `ptrace` to attach for process and then continue the process until tracee has been stopped (got SIGSTOP/SIGTRAP) ,I wait for that with `waitpid` .

Usually that work fine, but sometime I see that even tracee has been stopped, `waitpid` (the second one ,after PTRACE_CONT) still stuck and not finish.

Am I wrong with `waitpid`?

Code:

```
if(ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH,pid,0,0)==-1){
    goto error;
}

int status;
if(waitpid(pid,&status,__WALL)==-1)
      goto error;


if(-1==(ptrace(PTRACE_CONT,pid,NULL,NULL))
          goto error;




if(waitpid(pid,&status,__WALL)==-1)
      goto error;
```

Comment: Which one of the two calls to `waitpid` does not end? Also, can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: It looks from the man page like `__WALL` is only documented for use with `waitid`, not `waitpid`.  What happens if you simply pass `0` for the `options` argument instead?

Comment: @Marco Bonelli the second one, after PTRACE_CONT

Comment: @yfr24493AzzrggAcom why are you doing the second waitpid() in the first place? It doesn't make much sense if you don't clarify why you need it. What's your goal?

Comment: I used the first `waitpid` like in man ptrace  `The tracee is sent a SIGSTOP, but will
              not necessarily have stopped by the completion of this call;
              use waitpid(2) to wait for the tracee to stop`